# Grid view pager row not visible

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have a dropdown enabled grid view i am using dropdown for page size with values 25, 50 and 100 but currently in database i have only 22 rows(which will increase in future) and page size of grid view is 25 so the pager row is not visible is there any thing to make it visible or it is the property of gridview to not show pager row when page items present is less than page size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is property of GridView. Minimum rows(25 in your case) must be there to show pager row. Set the page size less than the rows in grid view and you will see the pager row.